# The user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: workflow

For a few days I have seen the error message "The user does not exist or is not unique" flooding my trace logs. I noticed that my Workflow timer job is stuck on "initialized". Any idea how I can determine which workflow is causing this issue?

I tried increasing the logging level, there is also nothing to see in the eventlogs on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A running workflow wanted to get information from an account that did not exist anymore. I was able to solve this by cancelling the workflow and then running

stsadm -o migrateuser -oldlogin domain\olduser -newlogin domain\newuser -ignoresidhistory

to change the old login in all content databases to the new login.
See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141(office.12).aspx for more info.